# Normalizing product of features

Tags: normalization

Lets say we have two features x1 and x2 . lets say we do following:

- x1: Min Max scaling , x2: Min Max scaling
- x1: Min Max scaling , x2: Z score scaling
- x1: Z score scaling , x2: Z score scaling
  Now, if we have feature y = x1*x2, what would be the ways to normalize this product feature, based on normalization of individual features. I could treat *"y"* as a  feature and normalize as needed, but is there some theory/discussion behind normalizing it from knowing the normalization of individual features.

sedy